# error comparing an input field to a value in a database

Tags: c#, odb

[image]

Trying to compare a value I get from an input field to a value in a database using mysql, and I get the error `:Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-00911: invalid character'`

```
OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand();
            cmd2.Connection = conn;
            cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM Actors WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Actors WHERE Name = Omar ); ";
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("name", textBox7.Text);
            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if(reader[0].Equals(1))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        {
                            ID_VALUE = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
                        }
                    }
                    cmd2.CommandText = $"insert into Movies_Actors values(:ID,{ID_VALUE})";
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("ID", textBox1.Text);
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else
                {
                    doesnotExist = true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: it is already inside a while loop

Comment: It sais "Invalid charcter". What is that :ID doing in the values part of your insert-query ? values(:ID,{ID_VALUE}) ? does it expect : ?

Comment: `WHERE Name = Omar` will immediately fail. Try `WHERE Name = 'Omar'`

Comment: i tried all those solutions and it comes back with an error in another line

Comment: Can you possibly mean `WHERE Name = @name` because you add a parameter with this name?

Comment: ive added an image to the error line and the error itself i think it's better now to check the image to be more clear

Comment: The EXISTS part in your query seems redundant, and I still don't understand the Parameters.Add("name" part because your query does not have a parameter with the name `name`

Comment: i  fixed it thank u for helping :)